# Hide Dropdown when there are no MenuItems rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm building an action menu with the help of a Dropdown component which looks something like this:

```
const ActionMenu = ({ children, heading, ...props }) => {    
  return (
    <NavBarTopLeft>
        <Dropdown id={newId("action_menu")} bsSize="small">
            <Dropdown.Toggle>
                <Icon name="bars" before fixedWidth />
                {heading}
            </Dropdown.Toggle>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                {children}
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    </NavBarTopLeft>
  );
};
```

The issue/problem I'm facing here is that children here is a bunch of different MenuItems which all have a permission check if they should render or not. So sometimes I end up with with children that renders as:

```
<!-- react-empty: 644 --><!-- react-empty: 645 --><!-- react-empty: 646 --><!-- react-empty: 647 -->
```

So my question is if there's any way (css or react) that I can conditionally hide the Dropdown if that is the case. Have tried with ::empty selector as that kinda works but then I only target the ul and not the button itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I understand that u need to hide the drop down when their is no menu Item. The menu Item is coming from `children`.  So, When a `children` pointing to `null` u hide the drop down by following condition

```
    const ActionMenu = ({ children, heading, ...props }) => {    
      return (
        <NavBarTopLeft>
           { 
             children != null && 
               <Dropdown id={newId("action_menu")} bsSize="small">
                <Dropdown.Toggle>
                    <Icon name="bars" before fixedWidth />
                    {heading}
                </Dropdown.Toggle>
                <Dropdown.Menu>
                    {children}
                </Dropdown.Menu>
              </Dropdown>
           }
        </NavBarTopLeft>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Already tried that...children isn't null...it's the rendered output of children that results in empty/null

Comment: Maybe if I can "pre-render"/force render children and check that...??